# multiple clients accessing one email account over IMAP

Tags: email, postfix, thunderbird, imap, dovecot

I am using `Postfix` + `Dovecot` + `IMAP` + `Maildir` and I am accessing my server from two different machines (desktop and Laptop), i.e. two clients (`Thunderbird`). The are sometimes running simultaneously, and sometimes only one or the other client is running.

I have moved a message from from `Inbox` to `Archive` in one client, and then started the second client. In the second client, I see the message still in `Inbox`, and I see it in `Archive` as well.

I have checked on my server (this is easy because I am using `Maildir`) and the message is no longer in the `Inbox`. It is in the `Archive`.

So why does the second client show it bot in `Inbox` and `Archive`. Apparently, it has not realized, that the message has been moved while he was not running.

Is there a problem with syncing?

How can I make two clients accessing the same `IMAP` server behave orderly?

I have been using `IMAP` through multiple clients before, although the server was `Exchange` (not under my control, so I have no idea how it was set up). This problem did not exist.

Is there some setting in `Dovecot` ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of your setup, but I would suggest that you check that your Thunderbird clients are properly configured, before you start troubleshooting your IMAP server. In particular, you should make sure that in:

```
Edit
-> Account Settings
   -> Synchronization & Storage
      -> Message Synchronizing -> Advanced
```

You have all your folders checked as "Synchronized". You can also see per-folder setting when you right-click on the folder and select:

```
Properties
-> Synchronization
```

You might need to run the <kbd>Repair Folder</kbd> in the `General Information` tab, in case the folder is inconsistent with the server.